# Display tags for current post in sidebar

Tags: tags, sidebar

I'm looking for a way to list all the tags associated with the current post as a bulleted list in the sidebar, ideally with a CSS class for custom styling. All the plugins and code snippets I've found either display all tags site-wide, or display it as a tag cloud. My hunch is that it would involve calling `get_the_tag_list` outside of the loop somehow, but I'm a complete novice to WordPress development and am not sure how to get that working without guidance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance,

Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_tag_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list), you just need to set the 4th argument, `$id` to `get_queried_object_id()` which gets the ID of the main queried post/page outside of the loop. You'll want to check `is_singlar()` too though, in case the queried object is a tag/category with the same ID as a post:

```
<?php
if ( is_singular() ) :
    echo get_the_tag_list(
        '<ul class="my-tags-list"><li>',
        '</li><li>',
        '</li></ul>',
        get_queried_object_id()
    );
endif;
?>
```

The first 3 arguments are the HTML before the list, separating each list item, and after the list. The configuration I have there wraps the whole thing in an unordered list and all items in list item tags. The list has the class `my-tags-list` that can be used for styling. You can change that to whatever you want.