# Display current tag archive's name and description in sidebar

Tags: widgets, tags, sidebar

building on to my [previous query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287126/display-tags-for-current-post-in-sidebar/287131#287131), I'm looking for a way to display the current tag's name and description in the sidebar of the tag archive. I've tried using `get_queried_object_id()`, but that does not seem to work for archives.

(I'm already using the Custom Sidebars plugin that allows me to display a PHP Code Widget on the tag archive only, so I'm essentially only looking for a way to get the display itself working.)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance,

Julian

Comment: Have you tried `get_the_archive_title()`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/

Comment: Don't know how I missed that - worked like a charm! (In conjunction with `get_the_archive_description()`, for anyone who means to recreate this in the future)